# Plink - Remote interactive connection with bash script does not seem to work properly

Tags: bash, docker, putty, plink, redis-cli

I have a redis database on a remote docker host, and I'd like to access it through a single ssh script command via plink.

The script is simple (redis-script.sh):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter Redis Password."
read -s pass
docker exec -it my-redis-container redis-cli -a $pass
```

Which works fine when I do a standard ssh connection via putty then run the script after login. I am able to enter the password and connect to the db:

```
Enter Redis Password.
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

The problem is when I use plink, my plink command line:

```
plink.exe -t container-host /containers/redis-script.sh
```

I get this:

```
Enter Redis Password.
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
[6n
```

One issue is the mangled characters, but the biggest issue is that I can no longer type in any commands at this point.  I am able to interact when it asks for the password, but once it gets into redis-cli, I cannot type anything.

Perhaps it's the docker exec command which is messing up the interactivity?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Plink is not really intended for an interactive use. Why don't you use the PuTTY?

Comment: I am currently using putty, thanks.   I initially wanted to use plink to keep in the same terminal and be able to run inline commands rather than putty's "-m <file>" command, but this will work well enough.